# Application of the Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I was given an exercise in my real analysis class that reads as follows.

Suppose that $I$ is a nondegenerate interval, that $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, and that $f'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in I$. Prove that $f^{-1}$ exists and is differentiable on $f(I)$.

I don't see how the assumptions in this exercise are any different than the assumptions of the Inverse Function Theorem. That is, since $f$ is differentiable on $I$ and $f'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in I$, $f$ is continuous on $I$, $f$ is strictly monotone on $I$ and therefore is injective. It seems to me that all that this exercise is just an extension of the Inverse Function Theorem to entire intervals as opposed to a single point in an interval. So would it be sufficient to say that since the Inverse Function Theorem holds for an arbitrary $x\in I$ then it holds for all $x\in I$ and therefore $f^{-1}$ exists and is differentiable on $f(I)$? I'm just not sure how to prove this rigorously.

Inverse Function Theorem:
Let $I$ be an open interval and $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be 1-1 and continuous. If $b=f(a)$ for some $a\in I$ and if $f'(a)$ exists and is nonzero, then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $b$ and $(f^{-1})'(b)=1/f'(a)$

Comment: Could you state your version of the Inverse Function Theorem?

Comment: I edited the question to include the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: You can apply this at the end as you say. But I think you should argue why, as you say, $f$ is strictly monotone. Note that $f'$ needn't be continuous on $I$, so $f'(x)\ne 0$ for all $x \in I$, does not directly imply a sign on $f'$. It does, but why?

Comment: It implies a sign on $f'$ due to the Mean Value Theorem right?

Comment: That combined with the fact that $I$ is a nondegenerate interval. That is, let $I=(a,b)$ where $a\neq b$, then we can apply the Mean Value Theorem using the fact that $f'(x)\neq 0$ for any $x\in I$. That then implies that $f(x_2)-f(x_1)$ is nonzero for $x_1, x_2\in I$ and $a\leq x_1 < x_2 \leq b$ and therefore, $f$ is strictly monotone.

Comment: Why can you apply the MVT? $f'$ need not be continuous! That's the point I also wanted to make above.

Comment: Well, suppose $x_1,x_2\in I$ and $f'(x_1)>0$ and $f'(x_2)<0$, then, since $f'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in I$, $f$ would have to be discontinuous at some point in $I$, which contradicts the assumptions of the exercise. Therefore $f'(x)$ is either positive of negative for all $x\in I$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6544/discussion-between-martini-and-christopher-washington)

Answer (score 2):

It is a well known fact that if a function is differentiable, then it is continuous. All you need is this

"A continuous function ƒ is one-to-one (and hence invertible) if and only if it is either strictly increasing or decreasing (with no local maxima or minima)".

Answer (score 0):

Inverse function theorem requires continuous differentiability, which you don't assume.

Comment: Welcome to stackExchange henry, this is just a comment and it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The second para of OP states that $f$ is differentiable.  Is something different implied by continuously differentiable?